# Vertical ToggleButtonGroup in React?

Tags: reactjs, button, layout, react-bootstrap

Is there a way to make ToggleButtonGroups display buttons vertically instead of horizontally? I have tried changing the `orientation="vertical"` but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
    import ToggleButtonGroup from "react-bootstrap/ToggleButtonGroup";
    import ToggleButton from "react-bootstrap/ToggleButton";
    function App() {
      return (
        <>
          <h1>Some question ?</h1>
          <ToggleButtonGroup orientation="vertical" type="checkbox">
              <ToggleButton id="tbg-check-1" value={1}>
                Option 1{" "}
              </ToggleButton>{" "}
              <ToggleButton id="tbg-check-2" value={2}>
                Option 2{" "}
              </ToggleButton>{" "}
              <ToggleButton id="tbg-check-3" value={3}>
                Option 3{" "}
              </ToggleButton>{" "}
              </ToggleButtonGroup>
        </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: ToggleButtonGroup displaying horizontal buttons]

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: you need to check package.json maybe you are missing some library which cause this otherwise you are doing it the right way

Please check this URL

[click here this link contains both horizental and vertical design](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d14nn6)

```
import React from 'react';
import { ToggleButtonGroup, ToggleButton } from '@mui/material';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <>
        <h1>Vertical ?</h1>
        <ToggleButtonGroup orientation="vertical" type="checkbox">
          <ToggleButton id="tbg-check-1" value={1}>
            Option 1{' '}
          </ToggleButton>{' '}
          <ToggleButton id="tbg-check-2" value={2}>
            Option 2{' '}
          </ToggleButton>{' '}
          <ToggleButton id="tbg-check-3" value={3}>
            Option 3{' '}
          </ToggleButton>{' '}
        </ToggleButtonGroup>
      </>

      <>
        <h1>Horizental?</h1>
        <ToggleButtonGroup orientation="horizental" type="checkbox">
          <ToggleButton id="tbg-check-1" value={1}>
            Option 1{' '}
          </ToggleButton>{' '}
          <ToggleButton id="tbg-check-2" value={2}>
            Option 2{' '}
          </ToggleButton>{' '}
          <ToggleButton id="tbg-check-3" value={3}>
            Option 3{' '}
          </ToggleButton>{' '}
        </ToggleButtonGroup>
      </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is. Running your code both sets of buttons are arranged horizontally. Atm I have react-bootstrap, and mui/material installed. Is there anything else I need to get this running as expected?

Comment: Okay installing emotion/react and emotion/styled gets this code up and running. But now the buttons do not stay highlighted when pressed. Is this normal behavior? I was  originally importing ToggleGroup from react-bootstrap as you can see from above

Comment: There is no color effect or style I found but yes the button effect you can see on click.